# Hide some divs (it won't take space)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, show-hide

I have 5 divs. Each time I want only one of them to be shown in the middle of the screen. The problem is that the hidden divs takes space. Each div contain a lot of information so I don't want to create it each time I need to show it.

I simply used: `visibility="visible"` or `visibility="hidden"`.

Are there other possibilities?

Comment: use `display: block` and `display: none` instead.

Comment: See [What is the difference between visibility:hidden and display:none?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`display:none`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/display) to hide an element completely from the layout instead, which is documented as:

> none - This value causes an element to not appear in the document. It has no effect on layout.

[`visibility:hidden`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/visibility) will leave an *invisible box*, which is the problem you are encountering. From the documentation:

> hidden - The generated box is invisible (fully transparent, nothing is drawn), but still affects layout. Furthermore, descendants of the element will be visible if they have 'visibility: visible'.

The default CSS `display` value for a `<div>` is `display:block`, so to *show* the `<div>` again, just set the element back to `display:block`. Note that there are [other values for `display`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/display), so take care to set it back to it's original value (which might not necessarily be the *default* value).

Comment: ...and `display:block` instead of `visibility="visible"`

Comment: My problem in addition to "display: none" was that I had to do it to all internal divs (not the outside).

Comment: Could you wrap the internal `<div>`s in another `<div>` and change the display of that instead?

Answer (score 0):

use `display:none` if you use css or `.hide()` if you use jquery

Answer (score 0):

I would normally just use the jquery 'hide' method. This should hide the div's without them taking up any space on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Even invisible elements take up space on the page. Use the `display` property to create invisible elements that do not take up space.

```
display:none;
```

Read this for more info --> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/display